# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion error

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, return-type

I am trying to learn c where main function calls some other function returning an array (for example of string type).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* array_return(char* name);

int main(){
    char* name="orange";
    char* A;
    A=array_return(name);
    free(A);

    printf("%s\n","Check stored values in A");
    int k,n;
    n=10;
    for (k=0; k < n; k++) {
        printf("%s\n",A[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}


char* array_return(char* name){
    int k,n;
    n=10;
    char* A=malloc(n);
    char string[100];

    printf("%s\n","Store values in A");
    for (k=0; k < n; k++) {
        strcpy(string,"Numer of ");
        strcat(string,name);
        strcat(string," are: ");
        sprintf(string,"%s %i",string,k);
        A[k]=string;
        printf("%s\n",A[k]);
    }
    printf("%s\n","--------------------------");
    return A;
}
```

I am trying to store following values in array "A":

```
Numer of orange are:  0
Numer of orange are:  1
Numer of orange are:  2
Numer of orange are:  3
Numer of orange are:  4
Numer of orange are:  5
Numer of orange are:  6
Numer of orange are:  7
Numer of orange are:  8
Numer of orange are:  9
```

However, I get some following warnings

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 
'char'

incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char'
  from 'char [100]' [-Wint-conversion]
```

And, I get the following error when I run the program:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I would be very thankful if someone can help me to debug this code.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to/from a function. But you can pass a pointer. Read [ask] and use the debugger.

Comment: Your code has many issues.

Comment: "*for example of string type*" there is not type "string" in C.

Comment: @Olaf in the code, i might have misnamed, but I think "A" is the pointer in "array_return" function.

Comment: @Curiosity: In your title you want to return an array of "strings". Which typically would be an array of arrays or an array of pointers. None of these is in your code. And we are not a debugging service.

Comment: @Olaf you have been veryy helpful. thank you!

Comment: [correction example](http://ideone.com/CmRP7y)

Comment: Referring this "*`sprintf(string,"%s %i",string,k);`*": From `man sprintf`: "***DESCRIPTION** [...] C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying to take place between objects that  overlap  (e.g.,  if
       the target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer).*"

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not blindly "cast away" warnings.

Comment: Also reading from where a `free()`ed pointer points to is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

So the problems with your code are many. The one related to your error message is due to the fact that `A[k]` isn't a string and you're trying to print it out as one.

```
printf("%s\n",A[k]);
```

`A[k]` is the `k`th element of the memory pointed to by `A` and since `A` is declared as a `char *` that means that `A[k]` is of type `char`. To do what you're trying to do you want `A` to actually be declared as a `char **` like this.

```
char **A=malloc(sizeof(*A)*n); // We need n lots of what A points to
```

But your code still won't technically work because assigning `string` to `A[k]` just copies what `string` points to into each element of `A` so they'll all be the same. That is, until that function finishes and then you enter the realm of Undefined Behaviour as the memory used by `string` is no longer valid.

So what you want to do is copy the string in `string` into a new string that is pointed to by `A[k]`. The easiest way to do this is by using `strdup` as that will allocate space for your string and copy it in one function call.

```
A[k]=strdup(string);
```

Alternatively, you could ditch `string` entirely and allocate memory for `A[k]` and build the string you want directly in to it.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your suggestions and clarification.